# How to add defines to moc_predefs.h?

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, moc

Qt's moc.exe generates files `moc_predefs.h`, that contain some defines, that are included to every file that moc parses. Is there a way to add defines to these files?

I'd like to define some include guards in these files to prevent moc.exe from parsing some headers (mostly 3rd party headers like boost). I could define these guards directly as moc's parameter using `QMAKE_MOC += -Dfoo`, but that would unnecessarily bloat the makefiles, it would be much nicer to have it directly in the `moc_predefs.h`file.

I've noticed that flags defined in the pro file e.g. `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Dfoo` produce defines in `moc_predefs.h`. But obviously I don't want to define include guards for the build, just for moc...

Note I don't want to modify the generated files directly, I'm looking for a way to tell qmake / moc to add some extra defines to the files.

Comment: AFAIK, moc will not parse headers not listed in the project file. Since these are 3rd party headers, can't you just omit them from the project file's `HEADERS` variable?

Comment: @NikosC.: I think it does. I don't have these includes in the `HEADERS` variable, but if I wrap the includes with `#ifndef Q_MOC_RUN`, moc is 2x faster. I can't see any other reason why it would be so much slower other than it parses the includes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It proved to be quite difficult to add defines to `moc_predefs.h`, but there is another way to achieve the same result. Moc has a [command line option](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/moc.html#command-line-options) `@<file>`, that enables to read additional moc command line options from a file. So it is possible to create a text file containing defines like `-Dfoo`, one per line.

This file can be added to moc's command line parameters in a `*.pro` file:

```
load(moc)
QMAKE_MOC += @moc_ignored_file_guards.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

I didn't check it but I hope this might work:

> myproject.pro

```
...
# add this to the end of file
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Dfoo
load(moc)
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS -= -Dfoo
CONFIG -= moc
```

> I'm looking for a way to tell qmake / moc to add some extra defines to the files.

The problem is that `moc_predefs.h` is generated by C preprocessor (e.g. `g++ -E -dM  $$QMAKE_CXXFLAGS ...`), not by `moc` itself (in the latter case `QMAKE_MOC_OPTIONS` would do the trick). So `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` is the only relevant variable here.

Answer (score -1):

If you have access to Cmake, you could configure your build to use [AUTOMOC](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/prop_tgt/AUTOMOC.html), which will selectively run when it encounters a `moc` file dependency, and also provides the SKIP_AUTOMOC controll to exclude files from being `MOC`'d

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. If I wanted to add the defines to the auto-generated file manually, I would just add them...

Comment: I have revised my answer with a suggestion.

Comment: That looks cool, unfortunately in my case, I have a qmake project.

Comment: Cmake is a configurator/buildsystem generator, It is capable of generating your Qt Creator projects for you.

Comment: That's true, but the project I work on is quite large, I can't just switch it to cmake in a reasonable time frame.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I was going to suggest you try the solution in the other answer... but the other answer is gone?